# Is Javascript prototype similar to PHP static method?

Tags: php, javascript

I am learning some Javascript but I have a question about `prototype`

**Is prototype in this case similar to PHP static method since all the instances share it?**

Javascript

```
var Person = function(){
   this.name = "Test Person";
}

Person.prototype.work = function(){
   return this.name + "is working";
}
```

PHP

```
class Person($personName){

   public static working(){
      return $personName . "is working";
   }
}

$person1 = new Person("Joe").working();
$person2 = new Person("Mike").wokring();
```

Comment: Static methods are not associated with an instance of the object. Non-static methods (also called instance methods) are.

Comment: right, so all the instances share the same method right?

Comment: All C-like languages are somewhat similar in syntax etc. but a static function is not really the same as prototyping, and this is one of the big differences between PHP and JS, as JS is prototype based and lets you create instances of objects.

Comment: Also, your PHP is not valid; getting PHP that would do the same as the Javascript would show you the difference.

Comment: Please tell me that "class Person($personName)" compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical answer is no.  The underlying implementation of a prototyped function is not the same as the implementation of a static method in a C-like language.

...however, in practice, you can consider their general usage to be similar to `public-static` methods.
More similar would be prototyped properties compared to public-static members.

They aren't called the same way, but the concept of a method or a property which sits on the "class"/constructor, and is accessible to each instance, and modifying these values, as shared values, impacting all other instances is very, very much like a `public static`.

There are a few other things to keep in mind, though, and this will either agree with what you consider the functionality of `public static` to be, depending on the languages you use...

The most important, of course, is that in terms of prototyped functions, they have absolutely ***no access to any private/instance-specific state, which is not publicly-accessible***.
So if you're used to dealing with `public static` functions which might be able to call private methods or use instance-specific variables (which aren't public members), then you're 120% out of luck.

The second thing to consider is that you can also create the equivalent of public and private static members/methods through closure.

```
var Class = (function () {
    var private_static_method = function () {},
        public_static_method  = function () {},
        private_static_property = 1,
        public_static_property = 2,

        class_constructor = function (a, b) {
            var private_method = function () {},
                public_method  = function () {},
                public_property  = a,
                private_property = b,

                public_interface = {
                    method   : public_method,
                    property : public_property
                };

            return public_interface;
        };

    class_constructor.method   = public_static_method;
    class_constructor.property = public_static_property;
    return class_constructor;
}());
```

Now, through closure, I've got "private static" functions and properties, which every private instance can access.
I've got public static methods, which I've appended as methods of the constructor function.
Then I've got the constructor function which doesn't use `new`, and just creates a new object (`public_interface`), which attaches whatever you want.
Any of the public methods of the instance can access any private methods/variables of that instance, thanks to closure.

None of this has anything to do with traditional classes.
But from a purely closure-based standpoint, this is how you could recreate all of these access-types, without driving yourself crazy, trying to shoehorn classes into JS.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no. I recommend reading through [Doug Crockford's article on Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) to understand what `x.prototype` means in Javascript, and how it can relate to more "classical" inheritance. Wikipedia also has [an entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) that may help you with the concept.